# How do I edit/add a birthday in the `people` app Cyanogenmod 11?

Tags: cyanogenmod, contacts, people-app

I have Cyanogenmod 11 M8.

I keep my contacts on the phone, not sharing them in the cloud, I prefer to run only AOSP software and [FOSS applications from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/).

Somehow I can't add/edit birthdays in the people app. Shouldn't this be a **basic** feature for a **people application** .

I know they are  somewhere because the [birthday adapter](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=birthday&fdid=org.birthdayadapter)  shows the imported birthdays from my VCF file in the calendar.

So how do I add a birthday?

Comment: I have the same problem with CM 12.1, so thanks for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Cyanogenmod People, to see and edit the Events field (birthdays and anniversaries only available in this case), the People contact has to be in an Account, not on the phone only. I also do not use a cloud service for my own privacy reasons so I use MyPhoneExplorer app for PC synchronization and the associated but seperate MyLocalAccount app for Contacts storage, both on Play Store. If you decide to use MyPhoneExplorer/MyLocalAccount be sure to synchronize contacts into MyLocalAccount. When I realized this solution and installed MyLocalAccount (I had already been using MyPhoneExplorer) the older existing contacts did not synchronize with MyLocalAccount and I still had no Events field. I had to mass delete all contacts on the phone (easy with MyPhoneExplorer) and re-synchronize with MyLocalAccount. BTW, I use Outlook on my PC. Problem solved. Yes Android can be quirky but that's why we use it, right?!!

Comment: Thx. That is a clear bug then, will try Davdroid.

Comment: Davdroid will do the trick. Right you need an account.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I did was exporting my contacts to a VCF file then importing them on my old phone which has a field for birthdays, then edited/added birthdays and saved/exported the updated contacts and imported it into my newer AOSP phone.

Worked fine. The contacts app on my new phone doesn't display birthdays but they show up in [Birthdroid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.rigid.birthdroid)

Answer (score 0):

Once you are in the People app and have chosen a contact:

1) click menu --> edit

2) choose Add Another Field

3) select Special Dates (special dates defaults to birthday, but also included anniversary etc.)

I'm on CM11 M8 as well, works for me.

Also, might be worth flashing the latest gapps http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps

Comment: Unfortunately the only fields I can select:`Phonetic name`,`IM`,`Notes`,`Nickname`,`Website`,`Internet call`,`Address`,`Email`,`Phone`. 
No `Special Dates` option available.

Comment: @Janghou You don't have "Add Another Field" button in the middle maybe more towards the bottom? Maybe try flashing the latest gapps too? http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps

Comment: The "Add Another Field" button only give above options.
gapps? It looks like you can't keep track of birthdays unless you invite Google?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug. I thinks it's a Google vanilla Android "feature" that's transferred over to Cyanogenmod. Google is very driven to have you on their cloud and have an account with them.

Comment: It's a bug or Google is Evil. And that itself is a major bug and a shame, but one that will never fixed by Google unfortunately. BTW it's a bug in Android AOSP not in CM.