# stock Contacts app: confusing or missing details

Tags: contacts, stock-android, google-contacts

I'm running Android KitKat 4.4.2 on a Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo device.

When I edit a contact with the stock Contacts app, I notice that:

- It is not possible to set a birthday field when editing a contact. For contacts synced with Google, it is possible to add this field in the Gmail Contacts field, and then it will show up in the stock Contacts app as part of the details for the given contact. Why can't I just add this info directly from the contacts app when I add a contact.
- I don't understand the Relationship field that one can set when editing a contact. For instance, I can add a relationship and select Mother from the drop-down-list, but then if I leave the text-box that follows blank, the entry is not saved. Of course, I can always select Relative from the drop-down-list and then enter the value Mother, but I don't understand what having "Mother" **in the drop-down-list** would be useful for (and the same goes for all other kinship values available in the drop-down-list).

Comment: have a look at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77750 or http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8417

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit/add a birthday in the \`people\` app Cyanogenmod 11?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77750/how-do-i-edit-add-a-birthday-in-the-people-app-cyanogenmod-11) or http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8417